# How CodeIgniter's Query Bindings Work

Tags: php, string, codeigniter, input, escaping

I have been wondering how exactly does CodeIgniter implement their query binding system. I have read that CodeIgniter will escape data by detecting the data type of the variable and putting quotes 'at the beginning and end of strings'. If this is the case, wouldn't I just be able to do something like:

`' OR '1' ='1''` and get through security?

I have looked for the file where CodeIgniter stores this but no luck. Maybe you guys have figured this out.

Answer (score 0):

CI query binding is implemented in `system/database/DB_driver.php`, line 578: function `compile_binds($sql, $binds)`

:wolv:

Comment: I saw how they added the quotations around the string, still I think it could be injected. @daBayrus